# Replacing text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to replace Name in span tag with DR Smith when the button is clicked. And I should do it using a replace(tag,value) function that takes two parameters. How do I do it please help. I have written a piece of code but it wont work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="q1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
<body>
Dear <span id="salutation">Name</span>;
<p>
It has come to our attention that your invoice 
</p>
<button onclick="format()">Format</button>

</body>
</html>
```

js code

```
function format(){

    var x = document.getElementsById('salutation')
     x.innerhtml = "Dr Smith";
}
```

Comment: `getElementsById` -> `getElementById`, `innerhtml` -> `innerHTML`, `format()` -> `replace()` (though you're not using the arguments anyway, yet)

Comment: where's the `format()` function

Comment: I changed it but it still wont work

Comment: I didnt wrote the fomat function yet because I couldnt figure out what to write in it as I am eally new to js

Comment: @NewProgrammer7 your button is calling `format()`

Comment: Pls update your code then ;)

Comment: Add a failing jsfiddle.net instead so that our users can help you.

Comment: So this one works the updated one i just edited but I was told to do it by making a function that takes two parameters, a tag and a value

Comment: _"told to do it"_ If this is part of a class, perhaps you should be asking for advice/clarifications from your tutor/professor etc.

Comment: its a practice sample test

Comment: In that case, all the more reason to get help _from the people teaching you_ so they can help you in the best way to suit your needs when it comes to the real test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function names need some slight modification.

Use `document.getElementById()`, not `document.getElementsById()`. (singular, not plural).

Also remember that JS is case sensitive. Use `.innerHTML =`, not `.innerhtml =`.

Now all you need to do is define your function taking two arguments: `function(tagId,tagText)`, then call it from your button `OnClick()` event.

Here is a working example:

```js
function format(tagId, tagText) {
    document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = tagText;
}
```

```html
Dear <span id="salutation">Name</span>;
<p>It has come to our attention that your invoice</p>
<button onclick="format('salutation','Dr Smith')">Format</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsById('salutation')` , it's  `getElementById` and 
 `x.innerhtml = "Dr Smith";` ,it's `innerHTML`.

```
   function format(){

          var x = document.getElementById('salutation');
          x.innerHTML = "Dr Smith";
    }
```